In Path of Exile, does upgrading the weapon in which a skill gem is socketed boost the skill?
In Path of Exile, there is a long equipment upgrade ladder for each piece of gear.  But suppose that one already has a well-linked weapon with skill gems optimally linked.  Assuming one is fighting mainly using the attacks from the skill gens.  Is there any reason to exchange the weapon to the one in the next higher level?  I.E. Does upgrading a weapon in which skill gems are socketed boost the damage inflicted by the skill gems?

It's been a few years since I last played. Is upgrading weapons a new feature added recently? Or are you referring to blacksmith whetstones/armorer scraps? Or just getting a brand new weapon with a higher base item type?

@qazmlpok My question is about getting a brand new weapon with a higher base item type.

Spells do not use the weapon stats for dealing damage*. Using Fireball as an easy example, the damage and cast speed are listed in the sidebar. The weapon's stats do not factor into this. Cast speed is also unaffected by the equipped weapon type.
This is in contrast to Attacks, which do use the weapon's stats and attack speed. Cleave, for example, references Attack Damage: (179-511)% of base and Attack Speed: 80% of base; this is for the equipped weapon's attack damage and attack speed, before socketed support gems.
Additionally, it does not matter where a skill gem is socketed. Attack/Spell gems can be socketed in boots or gloves without issue. They do not need to be in the weapon.
There are, however, still plenty of reasons to upgrade your weapon even when using spells. Any modifiers on that weapon (e.g. increased spell damage, increased cast speed) will still improve your damage. Weapons will have implicit attributes, and stronger weapons within a class will have stronger implicits. Wands, for example: the first wand has the implicit (8-12)% increased Spell Damage. The lategame Prophecy Wand has (36-40)% increased Spell Damage.
Magical item modifiers work under a similar principle: higher level items can get stronger multipliers. The prefix "Apprentice's" boosts spell damage by (10-19)%, "Runic" by (100-109)%, but Runic has a mod level of 84. The page List of modifiers for wands includes all modifiers that can appear on wands, including required level; Modifier details the generation.
Upgrading your weapon will not directly boost spell damage, but it is very likely you will find a better weapon that will be helpful, even if you need to rearrange your skill gems.

* Spells do not normally use weapon stats; with so many unique abilities and modifiers it's possible some item has "add weapon damage to your spells" or something similar. But if this even exists, it is not usual behavior.

I'm not exactly sure whether the original poster uses spells or attacks, so I would maybe put a greater emphasis on a "yes" for attack skills.

I just want to add that for crafting items and to see the possible mods on them (or even try to emulate crafting) there is a really nice page: craftofexile.com
